# jQuery .each function not working with dynamic variable

Tags: jquery

So I am working on a page where there are multiple menus where each menu is shortened by a determined number of list items with a "Show More" item added that tells you how many more items are in the menu.

I am using a jQuery .each function for the loop but the dynamic variable "how_much_more" is stuck with showing the wrong number.

The list currently returns Show More (3) correctly on the first menu but the second menu returns Show More (3) when it should not return a show more link.

It seems to me that the "how_much_more" variable is being overwritten in the loop.

Suggestions?

Edit: Here is the finished product: http://codepen.io/dsm/pen/dYegzg
Thanks for everyones' help!

```js
$('.routing-menu-wrapper ul').each(function() {
  var how_much = $('li', this).length;
  var limit = 5;
  var how_much_more = how_much - limit;
  if (!$('.show-more-routing').length && !$('.nav-expanded', this).length && how_much_more > 0) {
    $('<li class="show-more-routing"><a href="">Show More (' + how_much_more + ')</a></li>').insertAfter('li:nth-child(' + limit + ')', this);
    $('li', this).removeClass('active');
  }

});
```

```css
.routing-menu-wrapper li:nth-child(n+7) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="routing-menu-wrapper">
  <div class="moduletable">
    <h2>Menu 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 7</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 8</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h2>Menu 2</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: main issue is that `$(selector, context)` is valid but `context` is not an argument of `insertafter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your insertAfter to

```
.insertAfter($(this).find('li:nth-child(' + limit + ')'))
```

Currently, at the first iteration itself "Show More" is getting added to both `ul`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvmdLrz4/2/)

Comment: @Jonathan that wasn't the question. Pointing out why it happens is more important than enhancing to new features

Comment: The question states 

`The list currently returns Show More (3) correctly on the first menu but the second menu returns Show More (3) when it should not return a show more link.`

I do not see automatic update being mentioned.

Comment: This is true, but also the if-sentence gives a false positive on the second iteration if the first list is more than 5. See my answer for the full solution

Comment: Sweet - that works! While the comment from @turbopipp works, this is a tag bit cleaner. I also used !$('.show-more-routing',this).length to fix the problem stated earlier. I can sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me that the "how_much_more" variable is being overwritten in the loop.
>
> Suggestions?

Yes, this. :)

```js
$('.routing-menu-wrapper ul').each(function() {
  var how_much = $('li', this).length;
  var limit = 5;
  var how_much_more = how_much - limit;
  if (!$('.nav-expanded', this).length && how_much_more > 0) {
    $('<li class="show-more-routing"><a href="">Show More (' + how_much_more + ')</a></li>').insertAfter($(this).children('li:nth-child(' + limit + ')', this));
    $('li', this).removeClass('active');
  }

});
```

```css
.routing-menu-wrapper li:nth-child(n+7) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="routing-menu-wrapper">
  <div class="moduletable">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 7</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 8</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed `!$('.show-more-routing').length &&` because it was giving a false positive in the second iteration, and added `$(this).children()` to correctly target the right `<ul>`

Answer (score -1):

> The list currently returns Show More (3) correctly on the first menu
>   but the second menu returns Show More (3) when it should not return a
>   show more link.

Within `if` condition, setting current `context` to `.show-more-routing` object to `this` `ul` within iteration.

Within `if` statement , try selecting current `ul` by including `index` argument of `.each()` , using `:eq()`.

```js
$('.routing-menu-wrapper ul').each(function(index) {
  var how_much = $('li', this).length;
  var limit = 5;
  var how_much_more = how_much - limit;
  if (!$('.show-more-routing', this).length 
     && !$('.nav-expanded', this).length 
     && how_much_more > 0) {

     $('<li class="show-more-routing"><a href="">Show More (' 
      + how_much_more + ')</a></li>')
     .insertAfter('ul:eq('+index+') li:nth-child(' + limit + ')');
     $('li', this).removeClass('active');
   }

});
```

```css
.routing-menu-wrapper li:nth-child(n+7) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="routing-menu-wrapper">
  <div class="moduletable">
    <h2>Menu 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 7</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 8</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h2>Menu 2</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: none of them will return true if `how_much_more` is 0, the main problem is targeting inside the IF-sentence. Perhaps you got confused between `how_much` and `how_much_more`? See my answer for full solution..

Comment: Also, you must remove `!$('.show-more-routing').length`, because it will always be true after the first ul with more than 5, again :) See my answer for full solution. ;)

Comment: @turbopipp  See Question at _"The list currently returns Show More (3) correctly on the first menu but the second menu returns Show More (3) when it should not return a show more link."_

Comment: It is also about a dynamic variable :) I read that as infinite menus and infinite items. _a page where there are multiple menus_ I stand by my downvote still, the only new thing you did bring to the table was index and :eq, which is nifty.

Comment: @turbopipp  If interpret requirement correctly, given `html` at Question` , second `ul` should not have `.show-more-routing` element appended . Yes, you are correct. See updated post. Added `context` to `!$('.show-more-routing', this).length`

Comment: @turbopipp _"It is also about a dynamic variable :) I read that as infinite menus and infinite items. a page where there are multiple menus I stand by my downvote still, the only new thing you did bring to the table was index and :eq, which is nifty."_ Yes. This is user prerogative. Including description , reason accompanying "downvote" , which appear clear above , not required by SO , though could possibly be helpful to user that posted answer , OP , SO.